# How to merge two array of objects according to custom criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

Following are two arrays

```
arr1 = [
  { item1: 1, id: 1 },
  { item1: 4, id: 3 }
 ];

arr2 = [
  { item2: 1, id: 2 },
  { item2: 2, id: 3 }
 ];
```

And I need merged array like

```
 arr3 = [
   { item1: 1, id: 1 },
   { item2: 1, id: 2 },
   { item1: 4, item2: 2, id: 3 }
  ];
```

How can this be achieved?

Edit: if both array have object with same id, then I want to merge it. In example there is an object each in two array with id 3. So It is merged as shown.

Comment: what exactly is your criteria here?

Comment: @Praveen just guessing, but I'd say that objects with the same `id` will have both `item1` and `item2` in the same object.

Answer (score 1):

`array#concat` both of your array and group the object based on the `id` using `array#reduce`, merge object having same `id`. Then extract out all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var arr1 = [ { item1: 1, id: 1 }, { item1: 4, id: 3 } ], 
    arr2 = [ { item2: 1, id: 2 }, { item2: 2, id: 3 } ],
    result = Object.values([].concat(arr1, arr2).reduce((r,o) => {
          r[o.id] = r[o.id] || {};
          Object.assign(r[o.id], o);
          return r;
        },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var arr1 = [
  { item1: 1, id: 1 },
  { item1: 4, id: 3 }
 ];

var arr2 = [
  { item2: 1, id: 2 },
  { item2: 2, id: 3 }
];

var hash = {};
arr1.forEach(elem => { hash[elem.id] = {...hash[elem.id], ...elem} });
arr2.forEach(elem => { hash[elem.id] = {...hash[elem.id], ...elem} });

var result = Object.keys(hash).map(id => hash[id]);
```

What I've tried to do is construct an object like this:

```
{
   1: { item1: 1, id: 1 }
   2: { item2: 2, id: 2 },
   3: { item1: 4, item2: 2, id: 3 }
}
```

and then convert it back to array in the format which you wanted

**Note:** I haven't tested this code.

Comment: I just tested, It gives only `[ { item1: 4, id: 3, item2: 2 } ]
`

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 `Map` with spread syntax in array and `Object.assign`

```js
const arr1 = [{ item1: 1, id: 1 },{ item1: 4, id: 3 }];
const arr2 = [{ item2: 1, id: 2 },{ item2: 2, id: 3 }];
 
const map = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((r, e) => {
  return r.set(e.id, Object.assign({}, r.get(e.id), e)), r
}, new Map)

const result = [...map.values()]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With LoDash:

```js
var arr1 = [
  { item1: 1, id: 1 },
  { item1: 4, id: 3 }
 ];

var arr2 = [
  { item2: 1, id: 2 },
  { item2: 2, id: 3 }
];

var ids1 = _.map(arr1, 'id');
var ids2 = _.map(arr2, 'id');
var ids = _.concat(ids1, ids2);
var uniq_ids = _.uniq(ids);

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < uniq_ids.length; i++) {
  var ob1 = _.find(arr1, {id: uniq_ids[i]});
  var ob2 = _.find(arr2, {id: uniq_ids[i]});
  result.push(_.merge(ob1, ob2)); 
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```